# is it possible to modify project.pbxproj via script

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, sh

I have simple script in my Xcode project. 
That creates a folder in the project.
The problem is that it is not automatically added to the project.

I need to add it manually.

I would like to modify the script so that the updated file to the project and the folder was already visible.

I think something like that implements cocoaPods.

This is script:

```
if [ -d $PROJECT_NAME/CustomViews ]; then
echo "dir exist"
else
mkdir $PROJECT_NAME/CustomViews
fi
```

Now I can see the folder CustomViews in the Finder, but  can add to its automatic to project via sh

Comment: Sure, edit the project (text) file as you see fit.

Comment: If you look at a list of changes and there in two places, you need to add something

C81B50D21C29DDEE00C246EE / * ViewControllers * / = {
                         isa = PBXGroup;
                         children = (
                                C8C012501C3FFFD30010D9DF / * AuthAndRegistration * /,

                C8C012501C3FFFD30010D9DF / * AuthAndRegistration * / = {
                        isa = PBXGroup;
                        children = (
                        );
                        path = AuthAndRegistration;
                        sourceTree = "<group>";
                };